# Online resources for summer schools in software engineering?

Tags: online-resource, engineering, europe, summer-school

I'm looking for an online resources that lists all summer schools of the actual year in a specific domain. Are there any sites? I just found one: [Summer Schools in Europe](http://www.summerschoolsineurope.eu/), but this site seems to be a little bit outdated and doesn't have a lot of summer schools.

In my case, I'm focused on software engineering and Europe. But if it is a world-wide source I wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that one of the best online resources for Software Engineering is [SEWORLD](http://www.sigsoft.org/seworld/). You can browse their archives and look for summer schools there.

Note that their search engine is a bit weird, if you go through "search the archive", put Summer school in the subject and "2010-1-1" in the starting date (when I leave it blank, I don't get recent results). For future references, here is the result of this query:

- ISSSE 2012 - 9th International Summer School on Software Engineering
- Summer School Marktoberdorf 2012] *Call for Application*
- LASER Summer School 2012: Innovative Languages for Software Engineering
- CALL FOR PARTICIPATION - 4th RiSE International Summer School (RISS) - Next Generation of Software Product Lines
- summer school VTSA 2011
- Summer School on Technologies for Realizing Social Networks and Applications
- CFP: 1st Insubria International Summer School on Open Source Software (IISSOSS 2011)
- Summer School on Mechanized Logic for High Assurance Software
- Canadian Summer School on Practical Analyses of Software Engineering Data
- UPCRC Illinois Offers Summer School on Multicore Programming
- 3rd International CASE Summer School on Practical Experimentation in Software Engineering - July 11-15, 2011 - Free University of Bolzano-Bozen
- Summer School on Programming Languages for Concurrent and Parallel Computing
- 8th International Summer School on Software Engineering (ISSSE 2011)
- [Summer School Marktoberdorf 2011] *Call for Application*
- LASER Summer School 2011: Tools for Practical Software Verification
- [CFA] Summer School on Programming Languages PL2010
- CALL FOR PARTICIPATION - 3rd RiSE International Summer School (RiSS) - Generative Reuse
- Call for participation to the 3rd International Summer School on Adaptive Socio-Technical Pervasive Systems
- CfP ADAPT Summer School
- DSM-TP 2010: 1st International Summer School on Domain Specific Modeling - Theory and Practice - Call for participation
- Call for participation: VTSA 2010 Summer School on Verification Technology, Systems & Applications
- 6th REASONING WEB Summer School "Semantic Technologies for Software Engineering"
- Summer School on Mining Software Repositories - June 2010, Kingston, Canada
- CfP: UPCRC Illinois Summer School on Multicore Programming
- LASER Summer School on Software Engineering
- TiC'10: Third International Summer School on Trends in Concurrency
- Call for Part: CASE Summer School, Bolzano, Italy, 19-23 July 2010
- CfPart: 6th TAROT Summer School on Software Testing
- 7th International Summer School on Software Engineering

Answer (score 4):

You should also check [this list](http://user.it.uu.se/~bengt/Info/summer-schools.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

For software engineering maybe you can find sth [here](http://lanyrd.com/search/?q=summer+school).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Dagstuhl Seminars](http://www.dagstuhl.de/en/program/calendar/?dag_type=345&dag_year=2012). In that space some summer (and winter) schools on SE are frequently offered.

Their list is updated very frequently, and they make available a schedule of events about to happen for a couple of years. This way, you can organize your time (and money) to attend any school.

Comment: Dagstuhl Seminars are typically, though maybe not exclusively, invitation only, and are generally not summer/winter schools per se. (That said, there may be some schools offered.)

Answer (score 1):

You can check [ABC Business Academy Summer School](https://abc-businessacademy.com/). It's not software engineering specific, but it hits the broader scope of the topic.